# cron job schedule

Tags: linux, rhel, cron

I created a cron job using `* */2 * * *` schedule. Can anyone tell me what schedule this refers to?

I guess it should execute every 2 hours, but it seems to execute every minute.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `0 */2 * * *` for running job every 2 hours

Answer (score 2):

This is how a cron job is laid out:
`minute (0-59), hour (0-23, 0 = midnight), day (1-31), month (1-12), weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday), command` An asterisk (*) can be used so that every instance (every hour, every weekday, every month, etc.) of a time period is used.
so use `0 */2 * * *` so this will run for every 2 hours,every day and every month...

Answer (score 1):

Cron jobs will execute any time there is a match condition on the time spec. An asterisk (`*`) means "all".

So, what you've got with your time spec is:

```
* */2 * * *
```

The fields are:

- minute
- hour
- day of month
- month
- day of week

So, what you've specified, in english, is **"run once per minute during even numbered hours"**. Sounds kind of silly, but `cron` will faithfully obey.

In order to make it run only once, every other hour you need to set the minute field to some specific number. Any number `0`-`60` is fine, but what you *don't* want is `*`.

As many people have already suggested, the following is probably closer to what you want:

```
0 */2 * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `0 */2 * * *`. See the difference?  What you have probably runs every minute every other hour.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your cronjob like that will make it run every minute (first `*`) of every hour that's dividable by 2 (the `*/2`), so that means it runs every "even" hour, the entire hour. From `2:00 - 2:59`, `4:00 - 4:59`, `6:00 - 6:59`, `8:00 - 8:59`, `10:00 - 10:59` and `12:00 - 12:59` both AM and PM.

If you want to run it every 2 hours you should explicitly put the minute counter to `0`, so:

`0 */2 * * * user /some/command/here`.